# OpenVPN - Blocking client-to-client traffic

Tags: linux, networking, iptables, openvpn

I have an OpenVPN server running on a Debian box. What I'd like to do is to block all traffic between clients connected to that OpenVPN server.

The server has a local IP of 10.10.10.1 and the clients get IPs between 10.10.10.2-10.10.10.8.

I tried using iptables, but seems that the traffic between the clients never leave tun0 so I cannot block it.

What can I do? Is there some iptables rule that can block traffic inside an interface? (tun0)

client-to-client is **NOT** enabled in server.conf, but for some reason users can still ping each other and communicate with each other.

Comment: Although I can't explain why you are having this problem, there may be a way around it. Apparently (from what I've read), OpenVPN has a built in packet filter that can control this type of activity. I won't go into detail, because I've never used it. But it is documented and easy to find with Google.

Comment: Please post your full openvpn configs and logs. Both from the server and clients.

Answer (score 2):

Seems that you have "client-to-client" option turned on in you server openvpn config. You should just remove it cause openvpn doesn't route client-to-client traffic by default.

Here is text from man-page of openvpn:

> client-to-client
>
> Because the OpenVPN server mode handles multiple clients through a single tun or tap interface, it is  effectively  a  router.
>                 The  --client-to-client  flag tells OpenVPN to internally route client-to-client traffic rather than pushing all
>   client-origi‐
>                 nating traffic to the TUN/TAP interface.
>
> When this option is used, each client will "see" the other clients which are currently connected.  Otherwise, each client
>   will
>                 only see the server.  Don't use this option if you want to firewall tunnel traffic using custom, per-client rules.

Answer (score 1):

Add a rule on the server to block all traffic between clients, e.g.:

```
sudo iptables -I FORWARD --src 10.8.0.0/24 --dst 10.8.0.0/24 -j DROP
```

Comment: The question clearly states that this has already been tried, and it did not work.